# Remove/Add asterisk for requiredif when dependent property changes value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following scenario:
Multiple requiredif DataAnnotation attributes. I made a custom label helper that renders a "*" aside for the properties that are decorated if requiredif attribute.
Now on the clientside I want to be able to hide/show if the dependent property changes value.

For a more precise example I have a model

```
public class Document {
public bool IsFake {get; set; }

[RequiredIf("IsFake",false,ValueComparison.IsEqual)]
public string Number{ get; set; }
}
```

Based on the label helper  that I made I have the corresponding label for Number with a red * in the UI. When I change on the client side from the is fake to the is not fake radio button I want to hide the *.

I want to do be able to make this changes automatic and not make a script that for the known fields does that, as I have multiple cases like this.

I was thinking maybe I could write a javascript code that attaches dynamically a change event to the dependent property input and a handler that would show/hide the required mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much the solution which I came up with.
It is the best I could do, but still needs some customization meaning that the span that contains the "*" it's custom for my pages' DOM.

```
            <div class="editor-label">
                <label ui-documentLabel" for="Number">Number<span class="span-required">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input class="k-textbox ui-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-requiredif="The field Number is required!" data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty="IsFake" data-val-requiredif-dependentvalue="False" data-val-requiredif-operator="IsEqual" id="Number" name="Number" value="" type="text">
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Number" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

and the  javascript

```
  var clietsidevalidation = function () { };

 clietsidevalidation.is = function (value1, operator, value2) {
//function that verifies that the comparison between value1 and value2 is true or not
};

 clietsidevalidation.handleRequirefIf = function (container) {



$('input', container).filter(function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-val-requiredif');
    return (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false);
}).each(function (index, item) {

    var params = new Array();
    params["operator"] = $(this).attr('data-val-requiredif-operator');
    params["dependentvalue"] = $(this).attr('data-val-requiredif-dependentvalue');
    params["dependentproperty"] = $(this).attr('data-val-requiredif-dependentproperty');

    var dependentProperty = clietsidevalidation.getName(this, params["dependentproperty"]);
    var dependentTestValue = params["dependentvalue"];
    var operator = params["operator"];
    var dependentPropertyElement = document.getElementsByName(dependentProperty);
    params["element"] = this;


    $(dependentPropertyElement).on('change', { params: params }, function (e) {
        var input = e.data.params.element;
        var inputName = $(input).attr("name");
        var $span = $('label[for=' + inputName + '] span', '.editor-label');

        var dependentProperty = this;
        var dependentTestValue = e.data.params["dependentvalue"];
        var operator = e.data.params["operator"];
        var dependentPropertyElement = $(this);

        var dependentValue = null;

        if (dependentPropertyElement.length > 1) {
            for (var index = 0; index != dependentPropertyElement.length; index++)
                if (dependentPropertyElement[index]["checked"]) {
                    dependentValue = dependentPropertyElement[index].value;
                    break;
                }

            if (dependentValue == null)
                dependentValue = false
        }
        else
            dependentValue = dependentPropertyElement[0].value;

        if (clietsidevalidation.is(dependentValue, operator, dependentTestValue) == false) {

            $span.addClass('hidden');

            var $form = $span.closest("form");
            // get validator object
            var $validator = $form.validate();

            var $errors = $form.find("span.field-validation-error[data-valmsg-for='" + inputName + "']");
            // trick unobtrusive to think the elements were succesfully validated
            // this removes the validation messages
            //custom form our solution as the validation messages are differently configured DOM
            $errors.each(function () { $validator.settings.success($('label',this)); })

            // clear errors from validation
            $validator.resetForm();
        }
        else {
            $span.removeClass('hidden')
        }
    });

});
 };
```

This is inspired by another post which I can't find right now, but when I do I will post a link.